# Javascript Function logging to console from another function

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I have a small problem, due to my lack of experiance with JS ...

I have a function in my file , which is logging to console correctly, but somehow, not returning same value it logged ( or maybe I do not know how to pull it ..)

```
function getStoragex() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('alertsOn', function(data) {
          var optionShowAlertsx = data;
          console.info("This is logging ok" + optionShowAlertsx.alertsOn);
          return optionShowAlertsx.alertsOn;
        });

    }
```

The logging is :

```
DATA true
```

Later on, I have this ( inside another function 
)

```
var optionShowAlerts =  getStoragex();
console.info("This is logging undefined " + optionShowAlerts);
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return` statement is inside the anonymous function you're passing to `chrome.storage.sync.get`. Your `getStoragex` function never issues a `return` and so a call to it gets the result `undefined`.

<s>If `chrome.storage.sync.get` is a *synchronous* function (which it seems like it might be from the name), you can do this:</s>

```
function getStoragex() { 
    var rv;

    chrome.storage.sync.get('alertsOn', function(data) {
          var optionShowAlertsx = data;
          console.info("This is logging ok" + optionShowAlertsx.alertsOn);
          rv = optionShowAlertsx.alertsOn;
        });

    return rv;
    }
```

*(That bracing style is unfamiliar to me, apologies if I've messed it up.)*

*Edit: It looks to me as though the `sync` in that name doesn't have to do with the function being synchronous or asynchronous, but rather with data syncing.*

If it's *asynchonous*, then you can't return the result from `getStoragex` because `getStoragex` returns before the result is available. In that case, you can accept a callback that you, um, call back with the result when you have it:

```
function getStoragex(callback) { 
    chrome.storage.sync.get('alertsOn', function(data) {
          var optionShowAlertsx = data;
          console.info("This is logging ok" + optionShowAlertsx.alertsOn);
          callback(optionShowAlertsx.alertsOn);
        });

    }
```

Alternately, *promises* are gaining a lot of popularity at the moment. You might look into using one of those (there are several implementations available). The result will still be asynchronous if `chrome.storage.sync.get` is asynchronous, though.

Comment: Just starting to read your reply, I immediately got the problem. I had the return in the right spot before, But somewhere along the line I moved it ... Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` statement return value to it `chrome.storage.sync.get` method 2nd parameter itself. it will not return to getStoragex() method.

try this

```
function getStoragex() {
    var optionShowAlertsx;
    chrome.storage.sync.get('alertsOn', function(data) {
           optionShowAlertsx = data;
          console.info("This is logging ok" + optionShowAlertsx.alertsOn);
        });
 return optionShowAlertsx.alertsOn
    }
var optionShowAlerts =  getStoragex();
console.log("This is logging undefined " + optionShowAlerts);
```